# No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope at MainActivity.this

Tags: java, android, sdk, progressdialog, main-activity

I am making an app with a ListView. That ListView needs a separate class where you can set the action that happens when you touch an item in the ListView. I programmed it do download a file and show a ProgressDialog.

The error is at this line of code:

```
myDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
```

At MainActivity.this.

Could someone help me to fix the problem?

The whole class is at http://pastebin.com/3rWEKz4r

Comment: Please post the complete class where the error resides.

Comment: Posted it :) Some text to post because #15characters

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code instead of posting a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to reference `MainActivity` from a different class that reside in completely different files.

Also, it is not the `BaseAdapter`'s job to inflate and display a `Dialog`; it is better design to have the `Activity` do it. Doing this will also solve the problem you are having since you will be able to reference the `Activity` directly.